# Identify the first row when a new sequence begins in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequence

I have a larger dataset with a lot of sequences. Example:

```r
Number <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Day <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
Letter <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")

df <- data.frame(Number, Day, Letter)

df
#>   Number Day Letter
#> 1      1   1      a
#> 2      1   2      a
#> 3      1   3      a
#> 4      1   4      a
#> 5      2   1      b
#> 6      2   2      b
#> 7      2   3      b
#> 8      2   4      b
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would like to create a new column that tells me when a new sequence begins. Example:

```
df_des
#>   Number Day Letter first
#> 1      1   1      a   yes
#> 2      1   2      a    no
#> 3      1   3      a    no
#> 4      1   4      a    no
#> 5      2   1      b   yes
#> 6      2   2      b    no
#> 7      2   3      b    no
#> 8      2   4      b    no
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: A sequence based on which variable? There are three distinct patterns here, all plausible. This could be as simple as a grouping operation (e.g., `dplyr::group_by`), or perhaps with `dplyr::consecutive_id` or `data.table::rleid`.

Comment: @r2evans thank you. I would like to create a condition that sets the id if also the two other patterns change. E.g.: if Number turns from 1 to 2 and Letter goes from a to b.

Comment: Is it feasible that `Number` and/or `Letter` could revert back to `1` and `"a"`, respectively? If so, is that a _new_ occurrence or is that a continuation of the previous grouping?  I suspect this could be as easy as `group_by(df, Number, Letter) %>% mutate(first = c("yes", rep("no", n()-1)))`, but whether that is correct depends on your answer to my question of reverting to 1/a.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one base R approach -

```
# Columns to consider for sequence change
cols <- c('Number', 'Letter')
# Create a new column with everything as "No"
df$first <- 'No'
# Replace the first value of each sequence to "Yes"
df$first[!duplicated(df[cols])] <- 'Yes'
df

#  Number Day Letter first
#1      1   1      a   Yes
#2      1   2      a    No
#3      1   3      a    No
#4      1   4      a    No
#5      2   1      b   Yes
#6      2   2      b    No
#7      2   3      b    No
#8      2   4      b    No
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` way using `row_number` in an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0

df %>%
  mutate(first = ifelse(row_number() == 1, "yes", "no"), .by=Number)

  Number Day Letter first
1      1   1      a   yes
2      1   2      a    no
3      1   3      a    no
4      1   4      a    no
5      2   1      b   yes
6      2   2      b    no
7      2   3      b    no
8      2   4      b    no
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option

```
 transform(df, first = c("no", "yes")[1 + !duplicated(Number)])
```

-output

```
  Number Day Letter first
1      1   1      a   yes
2      1   2      a    no
3      1   3      a    no
4      1   4      a    no
5      2   1      b   yes
6      2   2      b    no
7      2   3      b    no
8      2   4      b    no
```